# How can I safely uninstall one version of python without removing others?

Tags: python, macos

I went ahead and downloaded the latest version of python3 onto my mac from python.org/downloads/, however, I was having trouble using pip in my terminal, so I used Homebrew to install python via the command line. It looks like Homebrew installed a 2.x version. I also know that my mac already has some python2.x version built in. I would like to remove the 2.x versions and only use the python3.6.1 that I have. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Honestly, you might want to look into `virtualenv`

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects to your question: invoking different major Python versions, removing unneeded Homebrew-installed packages, and identifying which installation is in use.

---

Major Python versions, 2 and 3, use different command names to invoke them. The first, `python`, uses the system default according to your configured `PATH` environment variable and *should* default to Python 2, but does not on all systems. Reference: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Instead, **explicitly invoke the version you want**, e.g. by running `python3`. Note that virtual environments (created by running [`python3 -m venv <name>`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/)) will create an isolated *environment* using the Python version of your choice where `python` will always use that version, and `pip` will install packages relative to, instead of system-wide, which may avoid the requirement of superuser (`sudo`) privileges.

Note that Homebrew might not override the default versions provided by the system, requiring you to make changes to your `PATH` to force Homebrew's versions to be preferred.  After installing a package Homebrew will inform you of this type of information, and you can get the messages later by running: `brew info <package>`

Uninstalling a brew-installed package requires running: `brew uninstall <package>`

For more information, run: `brew help`

---

As mentioned above, identifying just which Python you're using starts with the `PATH`. To quickly identify the executable you invoke when typing `python`, `python2`, or `python3` into your shell is by running: `which python` — this can help identify if you're using the Homebrew installed version or the system version, or if you are using a version from an active virtual environment. You can also use `which` to identify the `pip` or `pip3` command location.

This gets you the first part of the equation. The second then boils down to: where does Python think things are?  Invoking it then running the following will tell you exactly where it thinks things (imports) are:

```
import sys, print
pprint(sys.path)
```

This can help track down issues related to why you can't import that package you just installed with `pip`.

---

I can *highly recommend* using a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to isolate your projects from system level packages and differences. Within one, `python` and `pip` will basically always behave as expected, as you determined when creating the environment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I ended up here after having the same question recently and ultimately came across [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) with a few simple commands that remove the "Python Releases for macOS"/"Python Launcher.app" Python versions while not touching the macOS default version in `/usr/bin/python3`.

Below is [the GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dlzi/c2cb7e39835cb2da868de47394cd4e83) quoted in its entirety at the time of writing for easy reference.

**Note that you must change the version number** in the below commands to match whatever version of Python Releases for macOS you have installed (you can find them by looking in the `/Applications` directory.)

> **1. DO NOT attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in `/System/Library` and `/usr/bin`.**
> **2. Multiple Python versions can coexist pacifically on macOS. So, uninstalling Python is purely optional.**
>
> To remove a different version, change `3.7` to the Python version you
> want to remove.
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 3.7"
> ```
>
> ```
> sudo find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/*' -delete
> ```